# Canadian equivalent to AMLIS database?

Tags: geothermal-heat, open-data, mining, canada

I am interested in *in situ* coal fires. In furtherance of this, I am hoping to find a database of Canadian mine reclamation sites, complete with incident or status reports and descriptions of specific problems.

I've poked around a very small bit in the Federal Contaminated Sites Inventory, but I'm hoping there might be something a bit more specific or targeted out there -- something more like the equivalent of the United States' Abandoned Mine Load Inventory System (AMLIS) database.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

[Federal Contaminated Sites Inventory](http://www.tbs-sct.gc.ca/fcsi-rscf/home-accueil-eng.aspx)

as well as

[Crown Contaminated Sites Database](https://catalogue.data.gov.bc.ca/dataset/crown-contaminated-sites-database) (British Columbia)

[Orphaned/Abandoned Mine Site Rehabilitation](http://www.gov.mb.ca/iem/mines/oa_rehabilitation.html) (Manitoba)

[Abandoned Mines Information System-AMIS](http://www.mndm.gov.on.ca/en/mines-and-minerals/applications/ogsearth/abandoned-mines) (Ontario)